# button1.enabled=true; fires textbox1.leave() event in textbox1.leave()

Tags: c#

why this sample code fires textbox1.leave() event again?

```
int counter=0;
void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

counter++;
textbox1.enabled=false;
button1.enabled=false;
Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString());

}
```

this code represents counter=2!!!!

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Check whether you're using that Field (`counter`) somewhere else. Or you have subscribed to the `Leave` event more than once, using the same handler

Comment: theese codes are in new solution. I simplified my project to this. you can try that code in your pc

Comment: That TextBox is probably the default ActiveControl (the Control that is focused when the Form is first activated). Set its `TabIndex` to a value higher than the Button's (if you have just those 2 Controls in there) -- Otherwise, defer the execution, with `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Enabled = false));`, so you don't *leave* the Control twice when the Tab key is pressed (I don't think this can happen using the Mouse), by resetting the ActiveControl. You can probably see it better if you move `counter++;` after `textBox1.Enabled = false;` (should print `1` `2`)

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter=0;
void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textbox1.Leave-=textbox1_Leave; //remove event 


counter++;
textbox1.enabled=false;
button1.enabled=false;
Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString());



textbox1.Leave+=textbox1_Leave; ///// and add again
}
```

I tricked that issue like that..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).